# jquery tab wcag accessiblity: role presentation is not allowed for given element; Ensures role attribute has an appropriate value for the element

Tags: jquery, tabs, wcag

Jquery [tab](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) is adding `role="presentation"` to anchors and as per [axe](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/axe/lhdoppojpmngadmnindnejefpokejbdd) tool , it is WCAG violation, how to fix this?

Element source

```
<a href="#tabs-1" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>
```

> To solve this violation, you need to: Fix the following: role
>   presentation is not allowed for given element
>   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, I can put `role="presentation"` on any element that I want.  However, by so doing, it makes the element a non-semantic element (the link essentially becomes a <span>).  There could be a valid reason for having a link that is no longer a link, but in this case, I think jquery is using the wrong type of element.  What's the point of having a link that loses its semantic meaning **and** the tab stop is removed (`tabindex` is set to -1)?  Just use a <span> instead.

The tabbing appears to be controlled by setting `tabindex` on the <li>.

The jqueryui tab is also setting `aria-expanded` on the tab itself, which is wrong.  All it needs is `aria-selected` (which it **is** setting).  The tab is not expanding anything.

However, the screen reader experience of using the jqueryui tab is very similar to the [tab on the W3 page](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/tabs/tabs-1/tabs.html).  That is, I hear the same announcements when using the jquery tab and the W3 tab (except for the superfluous "expanded"/"collapsed" announcements by jqueryui).

So the end result is that it works.  The fact that the link has `role="presentation"` is not really an error.  You should [contact aXe](https://www.deque.com/axe/) regarding that.  aXe tries hard not to give false positives and they are good about replying to problems.

Comment: asked the question in axe forum given by you, thanks for the reply.

Comment: would be interested in hearing their reply

Comment: here it is, https://gitter.im/dequelabs/axe-core , response: That looks like a bug to me, since the link also has tabindex="-1". Can you file an issue on Github?

Answer (score 1):

The code for the active jQuery UI tab is, strictly speaking, self-contradictory. I changed the order of the attributes a bit for the sake of clarity:

```
<a href="#tabs-1" tabindex="-1" 
role="presentation"
class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-1"
>Nunc tincidunt</a>
```

An `a` element with a `href` attribute creates a link, and links are natively part of the focus order (or tab order). However, adding the attribute `tabindex="-1"` takes it out of the tabbing order. This creates a disparity between pointer behaviour (the link can still be clicked, even though the jQuery demo tries to hide this by manipulating the pointer style in CSS) and keyboard-based behaviour.

In addition, a link (since that is still how the active tab is implemented) is not decorative; it is *functional*, so the attribute `role="presentation"` is misleading here. The attribute `role="presentation"` can be used for decorative images and layout tables, for example. In a tabbed interface, it is better to add it to the  `li` element that contains the link, as shown in the [WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#presentation_role).

One might fix this by moving `role="presentation"` from the `a` element to the containing `li` element, moving `role="tab"` from the `li` element to the `a` element, and temporarily removing/renaming the `href` attribute from the `a` element while the tab is active.